# 簡単な質問　JAVA

Tags: java

> 文字列 s と文字 letter が与えられるので、s 内の letter を全て削除した文字列を返す replaceWithChar という関数を作成してください。ただし、letter が含まれていない場合は、s をそのまま返してください。

この問題で以下のように回答したのですがエラーになりました。なぜでしょうか？
また答えを教えてください。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Main.java:5: error: no suitable method found for replace(char,String)
        else return  s.replace(letter,"");
                      ^
    method String.replace(char,char) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to char)
    method String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char cannot be converted to CharSequence)
1 error
```

**作成したコード:**

```
class Solution{
    public static String replaceWithChar(String s, char letter){
        // 関数を完成させてください
        if(s.indexOf(letter)!=-1) return s;
        else return  s.replace(letter,"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

char型からString型へ変換してからreplaceしました。

```
class Solution{
    public static String replaceWithChar(String s, char letter){
        return s.replace(String.valueOf(letter),"");
    }
}
```

[【Java入門】Stringとcharの変換方法まとめ](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/19544)

Comment: 解答のコードでもエラーになるのですが、これはこちらの環境の不具合でしょうか？

Comment: 同じ個所で同じエラーが発生するのでしょうか？ paiza.ioで動作確認したところエラーは発生しませんでした。